# Calculate RMS for regression line

Tags: regression, rms

The RMS for the regression line is: $\sqrt{(1-r^2)}\cdot sd(y)$ where $sd(y)$ is the standard deviation of $y$ -- let's call this eq 1.
Another way of calculating it is: $\sqrt{(\sum(residuals^2))}\cdot 2$; let's call this eq 2.

When I run eq2 in R I get different results vs when I hand calculate using eq1...

What could I be doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I edited the maths content of your question to make it more visible. Please check if this is what you wanted.

Comment: What quantity are you trying to compute the root-mean-square *of*?

Comment: I do not recognize the second formula.  It clearly has little to do with a root mean square because it doesn't even involve the factor 1/(count of data) that would be essential in anything deserving to be called a "mean" and the factor of $2$ looks arbitrary.  What is your source for this formula?